# Apply custom theme to Odoo app

Tags: themes, odoo-9

I am new to odoo, know only how to create and update modules and apps but have no idea about theming my modules

I have create my own app from scratch (depends on base only) and now I need to customize its look, something like changing colors, fonts and menus positions and behavior, all I have found while searching is to create a module based on website module and customize it, and frankly I have no idea how my module will get the changes I can made on the theme module?

I need step by step tutorial about this which is suite to what I know in Odoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For theme reference you can visit these Links:

- [Customize a theme](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-customize-a-website-theme-45400)
- [New theme For Odoo Website](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/new-bootstrap-theme-on-website-builder-58809)
- [ODOO Official Doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html)
- [Slide Share PPt By ODOO](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/odoo-create-themes-for-website)

This may help in your case.

**Edited**

Regarding : **"how to get my normal menus and its elements represented in the website"**

Below i am posting the [code snippet](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/data/data.xml#L5)  for adding the menu in website:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <openerp>
      <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="menu_my_menu" model="website.menu">
            <field name="name">MyMenu</field>
            <field name="url">/MyMenuControllerUrl</field>
            <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
            <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
        </record>
      </data>
    </openerp>`

Here `/MyMenuControllerUrl` is the url of controller which render your `template` .

I hope this may help you.

Comment: I read the official doc but still wonder how to get my normal menus and its elements represented in the website? does the snippets will? how?

Comment: hi @Yousof i have posted the code snippet for adding menu

Comment: @Parkash so far so good, but I meant with menu the menu item which opens a form view, so my question is how to link product menu item for example in the website so I can open it there?, remember that goal with this is just theming my module not to create a website, just style the module view and make it good looking

Comment: from the 'product menu item' you mean 'product  category' ?? please explore your  query (if possible  share a image link also)

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/14576e7.png in this pic you can find my module which has many menus with default theme I want to change its positions, colors, fonts, etc..., something like restyle it again and change its look according to my needs.

Comment: try these links: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-existing-css-creating-a-new-module-46099  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846826/how-to-add-css-files-to-a-custom-module-in-odoo-8

Comment: I am very glad with your efforts with me, actually I tried the links and server isn't open and generate error saying "ValueError: malformed string", I think it is because of different versions links are for v 8 and I am using v 9, if you can style your work thanks to give me guide how did you accomplish this

Comment: @Yousof the stack overflow link that i have shared is the working link ,In sort  #1 Create a css file ,#2 Override the default class or define your custom class  , #3 Place this  style link in your xml (inherit_id="web.assets_backend") and #4 add the xml  in __openerp__

Comment: 1- css created in static/src/css/spogaze.css, 2- css content is " .openerp .custom_style{
    margin: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
}"  , 3- created xml file in views folder with the content according to link with the inherit statement and added to openerp file but still the same error

Comment: also used the class in form view this way " <div class="custom_style">
                            <field name="name"/>
                        </div>"

Comment: error is in your __openerp_.py file ,refer this link http://odoo-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_01.html#manifest-file-openerp-py  h