# How to change the color of One2many background in ODOO?

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I am need of changing the background color of the table of one2many field completely to white for a particular one2many field. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add css files to a custom module in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846826/how-to-add-css-files-to-a-custom-module-in-odoo)

Answer (score -1):

As I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848585/4891717), you will need to add css styles to the form

1. You must create the css file in this route: `/module_name/static/src/css/module_name.css`. Example of file:

   ```css
   .odoo .other_class{
       background-color: red !important;
   }
   ```
2. Create the file `/module_name/views/module_name.xml` with this content:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <openerp>
       <data>
           <template id="assets_backend" name="module_name assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
               <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/module_name/static/src/css/module_name.css"/>
               </xpath>
           </template>
       </data>     
   </openerp>
   ```
3. Add the xml file to your `__manifest__.py`

   ```python
   'data': [
       'views/module_name.xml',
   ],
   ```
4. Add the class to the elements in the view

   ```xml
   <div class="classname">                            
       <field name="field_name" class="other_class"/>
   </div>
   ```

**Note**: I am asuming you know how to use CSS styles. Keep in mind that `!important` should be used sometimes as you are trying to override the Odoo framework styles.

Comment: Will this affect a particular table?

Comment: @navi yes, this will only affect the table with the class `other_class`. Maybe the css is not exactly what I have written, but the idea is clear. I do not know why somebody downvoted my answer haha

Comment: Thanks for the reply.