# How to hide default odoo dropdown navigation button on top lefft corner?

Tags: navigation, odoo

I have added ohrms_core as a custom_addons. Now I have 2 dropdown navigation button on top left corner. Can anyone tell me how can I remove the default navigation button of odoo and keep the ohrms_core? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/258nx.png)
I have tried turning it off from user interface-> view and I have turned off various views to see which one works. But I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the button. Here is [how to add CSS files to Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846826/how-to-add-css-files-to-a-custom-module-in-odoo).

After creating and adding a CSS file to your module, use this style to hide the button.

```
.the-button {
  display: none;
}
```

where `.the-button` is the selector for the button you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position` to `replace` instead of [after](https://github.com/CybroOdoo/OpenHRMS/blob/16.0/ohrms_core/static/templates/side_bar.xml#L3) like in previous version

```
<t t-inherit="web.NavBar.AppsMenu" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//Dropdown" position="replace">
```